# Using two arrays to sort into tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Please be patient as I try to explain the dilemma. I am trying to write a macro that will help me sort the following table:

[image]

and trying to sort by sales ID into another worksheet(within the same workbook) with these pre-formatted tables:

[image]

End result should look like below image where all I need to do is fill in the sales ID and the formulas to the right of the sales ID column calculate or perform lookups:

[image]

Problem is that my team has been filling the tables manually or using a combination of the sort function to fill in the tables manually. Problem is that this can be a pain when we have 10,000+ sales IDs and no automation. My attempt at coding this to help my team has not been helped by my limited vba knowledge - any assistance appreciated:

Edit: I made some modifications to Kelvin's code (thanks @kelvin!) and I want to clarify that all I want to do is paste special values those sales ID into my "Tables" tab based off of the positions of the pre-formatted table. See new image below as well as re-posed code. Note the formulas in my Tables tab without Sales IDs (my fault that I wasn't clear)

One last note: The last thing I am trying to solve to complete this is to scan two ranges and filter out the unique pairs into an array to make the array CFValues below dynamic - please help if you know how to do this better than me!

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortNCopy2TablesV2()

Dim CFValues As Variant

Dim r As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim CombStr As Variant
Const startRow As Long = 7 'kelvin added

CFValues = Array("P A", "P B", "P C", "P F", "M A", "SP A", "SP B", "SP C")


Set ws1 = Worksheets("Cashflow")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Tables")

r = startRow 'kelvin changed

'kelvin added
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(CFValues) To UBound(CFValues)
    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = CFValues(i)
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Cells.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0

With ws1 'kelvin added

    Do Until .Range("C" & r).Value = ""

        CombStr = .Range("C" & r).Text + " " + .Range("D" & r).Text 'kelvin changed

        For i = LBound(CFValues) To UBound(CFValues)

            If StrComp(CombStr, CFValues(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 'kelvin changed
                                    'kelvin added 1 lines of code:
                .Range("B" & r).Copy _
                        Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B:B")) + 1)

            End If
        Next i
        r = r + 1
    Loop
End With

'kelvin added
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim tempRow As Long
Dim numRows As Long

nextRow = 5

For i = LBound(CFValues) To UBound(CFValues)
    tempRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B:B"))

    If tempRow > 0 Then

        numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B:B"))

        ws2.Range("B" & nextRow + 1).EntireRow.Resize(numRows).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ws2.Range("C" & nextRow & ":" & "F" & nextRow + numRows).FillDown
        Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Copy ws2.Range("B" & nextRow + 1)
        ws2.Range("B" & nextRow + 2 + tempRow) = CFValues(i)
        nextRow = nextRow + tempRow + 5

    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Some questions. 1) What is the purpose of the sorting into tables? Produce a report that looks like your tables? 2) Is this a per month/week/year thing, or will new data keep arriving into the sheet? If regular thing, will new data arrive in the same table in cashflow tab, or will it be a "fresh start" each time. 3) What do you want to do with the data in the cashflow tab? Keep it there? 4) And most importantly, what is your current problem? That it is not working or that it is not finished, stopping by the point you want to "decrement InsertRow[] array, so that..."?

Comment: And which table is on "cashflows" and which is on "tables"

Comment: 1) Sorting into tables helps my team to deliver sectioned analysis of the data into 'tranches' for credit analysis.

Comment: 2) This is a weekly report. We get a huge inflow of data, especially during the summers. Sorry I wasn't clear on that. Assume a fresh start (I.e. New workbook each time), thus this question is scoped towards a one time 'sort'.

Comment: 3) Good question. Data in cash flow tab should stay there (first table image in the posting).

Comment: 4) The problem is that I am not experienced enough to understand how to manipulate arrays to perform the task. Nor am I confident that this algorithm will get me there. I have tried many do until configurations and messed up with too many if statements to the point where I am stuck.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain clearly. The topmost image in my post is on the 'cash flow' tab and the formatted table with the end result is my 'tables' tab. Please ask more clarifying questions , I appreciate the interest.

Comment: Ok. First things first. Have you tried using a pivot table? It seems it is going to match your purpose without the sorting. Second, would you be OK having these different tables on different sheets? Or must they all be in one sheet? Third, note that ActiveCell refers to whatever cell is higlighted / clicked on at the moment you run the Macro, hence with your current code, it will never change, and be the same for each iteration. Fourth, the last line in if block (ws1.Range("B" & R).Value =..." copies data from the table sheet to the cashflow sheet. Assuming that is wrong.

Comment: Fifth, the insertRow array will not change, so if you insert an element, it will be wrong unless you increment all array entries below the one you are inserting by one. 
I think it would be easier if you instead of copying data just made a sheet that would read from the cashflow table dynamically, either by having one sheet per "table" or by having a drop down selector where you choose which table to populate from. But Pivot is probably best. Upon answer of these last I will have a crack on it, but it might take time, depending on your answer.

Comment: 1. Yes, unfortunately, the tables must be on the same sheet. This is a constraint imposed on me by management, so the business end user dictates the headache here for my team somewhat.

Comment: 2. I agree. Pivot tables on separste sheet would be best,and then I could use a macro recorder and advanced filter. But once again, the constraint imposed by the end user (management) dictates that all the tables be pre sorted onto one sheet.

Comment: 3. I didn't know that about active cell. Was only trying to get the program to focus on the row below where my R counter was. Thanks for pointing this out. 4. You are completely correct, this is my mistake. 5. Yes. I don't know how to get the insertRow array to change. I am lost as to how to get it to do exactly what you are suggesting (I.e.increment all array entries below the actual insertion entry). Thanks so much for your comments.

Comment: Jeez, maybe you shouldn't for fear of losing your job, but someone should tell "management" to get their heads out of the stone age. Do they want you to print it for them as well, so they can get it into the paper archive? As I said, I will have a look at it, but it might take a while.

Comment: Is your CFValues "up to date"? Some seller-bucket pairs in the cashflows table are not present. Do you have a list of all possible combinations? Or could it be any? If so, do you have a list of all possible sellers and buckets?

Comment: Heh, thanks. Just trying to expand my job into more tasks than just manual sort(by clicking filters), copy and paste. Hopefully my team can appreciate the time saver since they all have more than enough to do without having to manually sort 100s of entries. Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Hehe. It looks like a fun problem to solve. I might use different sheets and then copy them into one after that. Seems easier to me right now. As long as it all ends up in a sheet like your Tables sheet, I am assuming that is OK. Do you have the values for seller and bucket?

Comment: The trick here is that you will always have 4 bucket classes: A, B,C, F. The seller class can vary from 1 type to potentially 10 types. Meaning the number of sorted tables will be some multiple of 4. To answer your question, CF Values array is limited (and doesn't contain all value pairs) because I was trying to establish some base cases for testing.

Comment: You can assume for the sake of testing or establishing a base case, that seller class consists of 3 types: P, SP, and M. Bucket class is 4 types: A, B, C, F. Obviously, you can see what is on the horizon here. Once we establish a base case for this example of potentially 12 tables. I am going to try and figure out how to use an advanced filter to dynamically populate distinct value pairs into CF Values. That way this macro can be used in perpetuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gudal has written a workable code to generate the tables. Please find the complete code with small changes to gudal's code and the samples of input and output.
The code:

```
Private Sub SortNCopyTables2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim saleIDs() As Variant
Dim sellerClass() As Variant
Dim bucketClass() As Variant



Dim cashFlowSheet As Worksheet
Set cashFlowSheet = Worksheets("CashFlow")

Dim lastSaleIDRow As Long
lastSaleIDRow = cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

saleIDs = cashFlowSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastSaleIDRow).Value
sellerClass = cashFlowSheet.Range("B2:B" & lastSaleIDRow).Value
bucketClass = cashFlowSheet.Range("C2:C3" & lastSaleIDRow).Value

Dim classPairsArray() As Variant
Dim classPairs() As String
ReDim Preserve classPairs(0)
ReDim Preserve classPairsArray(0)
Dim size As Long
size = 0
Dim saleID As String

Dim tempArray() As String
For counter = 1 To UBound(saleIDs, 1)
    sellerBucketString = sellerClass(counter, 1) + " & " + bucketClass(counter, 1)

    If UBound(Filter(classPairs, sellerBucketString)) < 0 Then

        ReDim Preserve classPairs(size)

        classPairs(size) = sellerBucketString

        ReDim Preserve classPairsArray(size)

        ReDim Preserve tempArray(0)
        tempArray(0) = sellerBucketString

        classPairsArray(size) = tempArray

        size = size + 1
    End If

    Dim position As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(classPairsArray)
        tempArray = classPairsArray(i)

        If sellerBucketString = tempArray(0) Then
            tempArray = classPairsArray(i)
            ReDim Preserve tempArray(UBound(tempArray) + 1)
            tempArray(UBound(tempArray)) = saleIDs(counter, 1)

            classPairsArray(i) = tempArray
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i

Next counter

'loop through array and write to worksheet
Dim tablesSheet As Worksheet
Set tablesSheet = Worksheets("Tables")
'clear the tableSheet, just in case
'org: tablesSheet.Rows(10 & ":" & tablesSheet.Rows.Count).Clear
tablesSheet.Cells.Clear  'kelvin edited

Dim SaleIDRange, BalanceRange, MonthlyRange, RateRange As Range 'Change the letters and starting rows as necessary
Set SaleIDRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("A2:A" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
Set BalanceRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("D2:D" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
Set MonthlyRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("E2:E" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row) ' not used now but assume is used for npv / price calcs
Set RateRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("F2:F" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)

Dim tRow As Long
tRow = 10 ' this is where I start to build my table
Dim row As Long
Dim tempSumRow As Range

For i = 0 To UBound(classPairsArray)
    Dim tableStartRow As Long
    tableStartRow = tRow + 1
    Dim tableSellerBucketGroup As String
    Dim tableArray() As String
    tableArray = classPairsArray(i)
    With tablesSheet
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = "Sale ID"
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Value = "NPV"
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Value = "Price"
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Value = "Balance"
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Value = "Rate"
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        tRow = tRow + 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(tableArray)
            .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = tableArray(j)
            '.Cells(tRow, 2).Value = ??? NPV formula?
            '.Cells(tRow, 3).Value = ??? price formula?
            'org: .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + BalanceRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0))"
            .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + BalanceRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0)),)"  'kelvin edited
            .Cells(tRow, 4).NumberFormat = "$  #,##0.00"  'kelvin edited
            'org: .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + RateRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0))"
            .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + RateRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0)),)"   'kelvin edited
            .Cells(tRow, 5).NumberFormat = "0%"  'kelvin edited
            .Cells(tRow, 2).Formula = "=IFERROR(NPV(RC[3],RC[2]),)"  'kelvin added.
            .Cells(tRow, 2).NumberFormat = "$  #,##0.00"   'kelvin added.
            .Cells(tRow, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(RC[-1]/RC[1],)"  'kelvin added.
            .Cells(tRow, 3).NumberFormat = "0%"   'kelvin added.

            tRow = tRow + 1
        Next j
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = tableArray(0)
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Formula = "=SUM(B" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":B" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        'org: .Cells(tRow, 3).Formula = "=AVERAGE(C" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":C" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
         .Cells(tRow, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(RC[-1]/RC[1],)"   'kelvin added.
         .Cells(tRow, 3).NumberFormat = "0%"    'kelvin added.
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=SUM(D" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":D" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        'org: .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=AVERAGE(E" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":E" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        Set tempSumRow = tablesSheet.Range("A" + CStr(tRow) + ":E" + CStr(tRow))
        With tempSumRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With tempSumRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        tRow = tRow + 2
    End With
Next i
tablesSheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Sample input and sample output:
[image: Sorted Tables]

Thanks to gudal.

Answer (score 1):

According to your codes, the header of the first table starts at cell B6 and the first row of data starts at B7. Modifying your macros, I manage to do the sorting and place the result on the Tables sheet. However, I can't calculate the NPV for you because I don't know the exact formula. Please find the codes:

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub SortNCopy2TablesV2()

    Dim CFValues As Variant
    'Dim InsertRow As Variant
    Dim R As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim CombStr As Variant
    Const startRow As Long = 7 'kelvin added

    CFValues = Array("P A", "P B", "P C", "P F", "M A", "SP A", "SP B", "SP C")
   ' InsertRow = Array(6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41)

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Cashflow")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Tables")

    R = startRow 'kelvin changed

    'kelvin added
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(CFValues) To UBound(CFValues)
        Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = CFValues(i)
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Cells.Clear
            ActiveSheet.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ws1 'kelvin added
       'org: Do Until ws1.Range("C" & R).Value = ""
        Do Until .Range("C" & R).Value = ""

           'org:  CombStr = ws1.Range("C" & R).Text + "" + ws1.Range("D" & R).Text
            CombStr = .Range("C" & R).Text + " " + .Range("D" & R).Text 'kelvin changed

            For i = LBound(CFValues) To UBound(CFValues)
                'org: If StrComp(CombStr, CFValues(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                If StrComp(CombStr, CFValues(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 'kelvin changed
                    'Return value of first insert row in InsertRow[] array -
                    ' i.e. if P A, then it should return row 6 for insertion, if P B, then row 11, etc.
                    'insert new row, copying and pasting the formulas down and copying the sales ID
                    'Insert Sales ID value into Table tab
                    'org: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Copy
                    'org: ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    'org:  ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    'org:  Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    'org:  ws1.Range("B" & R).Value = ws2.Range("B" & InsertRow(i) + 1).Value

                    'kelvin added 1 lines of code:
                    .Range("A" & R).EntireRow.Copy _
                            Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("A" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B:B")) + 1)

                    'decrement InsertRow[] array, so that the
                    'program always knows where to find the next tables for insertion
                'Else
                End If
            Next i
            R = R + 1
        Loop
    End With

    'kelvin added
    ws2.Cells.Clear
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim tempRow As Long
    nextRow = startRow
    For i = LBound(CFValues) To UBound(CFValues)
        tempRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B:B"))
        If tempRow > 0 Then
            ws1.Range("A" & startRow - 1).EntireRow.Copy ws2.Range("A" & nextRow - 1)
            Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Copy ws2.Range("B" & nextRow)
            ws2.Range("A" & nextRow + tempRow) = CFValues(i)
            nextRow = nextRow + tempRow + 5
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

(Oops... I can't post Image. Please find the pasted text of input and output)
Sample Input:

Sale ID S Class B Class Balance Month   Rate
1   P   A   100 20  5
2   P   A   200 25  4
3   P   A   300 30  3
4   SP  C   400 35  2
5   SP  C   500 40  1
6   M   C   600 45  2
7   M   B   700 50  3
8   M   B   800 55  4
9   P   F   900 60  5
10  SP  F   1000    55  6
11  M   F   1100    50  7
12  M   A   1200    45  8
13  Sp  B   1300    40  9
14  Sp  C   1400    35  10

Sample Output:

```
Sale ID S Class B Class Balance Month   Rate
1   P   A   100 20  5
2   P   A   200 25  4
3   P   A   300 30  3
```

P A

```
Sale ID S Class B Class Balance Month   Rate
9   P   F   900 60  5
```

P F

```
Sale ID S Class B Class Balance Month   Rate
12  M   A   1200    45  8
```

M A

```
Sale ID S Class B Class Balance Month   Rate
13  Sp  B   1300    40  9
```

SP B

```
Sale ID S Class B Class Balance Month   Rate
4   SP  C   400 35  2
5   SP  C   500 40  1
14  Sp  C   1400    35  10
```

SP C

Please comment. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is definitely on the right track. See above for updated code (which is just slightly three lines modified from yours) and the new image I posted. Two things: (1) I need a way to insert rows into those pre-formatted tables so that I can copy and paste special values the sales ID only-thus my poorly constructed edits (2) To finish this, I want to make CFValues array dynamic by writing this: `CFValues = WorkSheet("Cashflows").Range("$C$7:$D$65536").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo`  Thoughts? Objections and how I can do it better?

Comment: I solved (1)  (see above updated code - thanks to you!) and now I just need to figure out (2) because I am still unsure how an array is going to self populate......

Comment: According to your newly updated code (about 3 hours before my reply), the code only copy one cell (instead of entire row):  With ws1 ...
                .Range("B" & r).Copy _
                        Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(CFValues(i)).Range("B:B")) + 1)
... End With

Comment: Could you please provide me sample data in the CashFlow sheet and sample output and the formula to calculate Balance and Rate? Hopefully I can't provide a complete result without needing to manually enter formulas =SUM(...), = IFERROR(NPV(... , ...

Comment: Your CFValues array did not include "M C", "M B",...  {Sorry to send you so many comments because when I hit the Enter key, the comment was automatically sent, instead of the next line}. You may arrange of sequence of the items in the array because the output Table follows that sequence. Thanks.

Comment: Balance formula = `IFERROR(INDEX(Cashflow!E$7:E$35,MATCH(Tables!B5,Cashflow!B$7:B$35)),)` Rate formula = `IFERROR(INDEX(Cashflow!G$7:G$35,MATCH(Tables!B5,Cashflow!B$7:B$35)),)` ; Hopefully it's obvious that I copied the formulas down for each table. And it's true - I didn't include all values in my CFValues because I was testing a limited subset. Once again - don't modify the code to duplicate the formulas. Only copy/paste special values for the sale ID. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please refer to the 3rd answers below for detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you received an other answer while I wrote this code, but though I would post it anyway. The code below should be pasted to the vba part of the Tables sheet. You should then create a button on that sheet (in developer tab) and assign it to the macro StartSortClick

This code assumes the following, and it must be changed accordingly for what is not correct. If you comment below where my assumptions are wrong, I can update it for you, or you can do it yourself.

1. CashFlow tab has headings in row 1, with Sale ID in A1, Seller Class in B1, etc
2. In the tables tab, you want the first table to start at row 10, and in column A, so that Sale ID of the first table is written in A10.
3. I have not entered formulas for price and npv, provide your formulas if you wish me to.
4. Font is changable too. Just to it for the entire sheet at the end of the code (code will overwrite manual font change before code is run, to ensure table borders are placed properly).

I am sure it could have been done neater, and I think it could be slow with 10000+ rows but it does what you ask. Using 2-dimensional arrays would be quicker, I see now. Working on a version of that (because I need to get better at using arrays myself, and your problem was fun working on)

```
Public Sub StartSortClick()
If MsgBox("This will rebuild the Tables tab! Continue?", vbYesNo, "Rebuild Tables Tab?") Then
    SortNCopyTables
End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortNCopyTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sheetCollection As Collection
Set sheetCollection = New Collection

Dim cashFlowSheet As Worksheet
Set cashFlowSheet = Worksheets("CashFlow")

Dim SaleIDRange, BalanceRange, MonthlyRange, RateRange As Range 'Change the letters and starting rows as necessary
Set SaleIDRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("A2:A" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
Set BalanceRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("D2:D" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
Set MonthlyRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("E2:E" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row) ' not used now but assume is used for npv / price calcs
Set RateRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("F2:F" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)

'loop through all rows, if encountering a new seller-bucket combo, create a new sheet, name it that seller-bucket combo and add it to the sheetCollection
Dim cRow As Long
cRow = 2 ' should be the location of first cashflow entry
Dim sellerBucketString As String
Dim tempSheet As Worksheet
Dim firstUnusedRow As Long
Do Until cashFlowSheet.Cells(cRow, 1) = "" ' here you should change the 1 to whatever column is your Sale ID column (mine are in A)
    sellerBucketString = cashFlowSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).Value + " & " + cashFlowSheet.Cells(cRow, 3).Value
    If Not InCollection(sheetCollection, sellerBucketString) Then
        'create new sheet and add to collection
        With ThisWorkbook
            Set tempSheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            tempSheet.Name = sellerBucketString
            sheetCollection.Add tempSheet, tempSheet.Name
        End With
    End If

    ' select worksheet and insert row at the bottom)
    Set tempSheet = sheetCollection.Item(sellerBucketString)
    firstUnusedRow = tempSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).row
    tempSheet.Cells(firstUnusedRow, 1).Value = cashFlowSheet.Cells(cRow, 1).Value
    cRow = cRow + 1
Loop


'loop through sheets in the collection and create appropriate report tables in Tables sheet
Dim tablesSheet As Worksheet
Set tablesSheet = Worksheets("Tables")
'clear the tableSheet, just in case
tablesSheet.Rows(10 & ":" & tablesSheet.Rows.Count).Clear

Dim tRow As Long
tRow = 10 ' this is where I start to build my table
Dim row As Long
Dim tempSumRow As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In sheetCollection
    Dim tableStartRow As Long
    tableStartRow = tRow + 1
    With tablesSheet
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = "Sale ID"
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Value = "NPV"
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Value = "Price"
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Value = "Balance"
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Value = "Rate"
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        tRow = tRow + 1

        For row = 2 To ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
            .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = ws.Cells(row, 1).Value
            '.Cells(tRow, 2).Value = ??? NPV formula?
            '.Cells(tRow, 3).Value = ??? price formula?
            .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + BalanceRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0))"
            .Cells(tRow, 4).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + RateRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0))"
            .Cells(tRow, 5).NumberFormat = "0.0 %"
            tRow = tRow + 1
        Next row
        ' add summing row
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = ws.Name
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Formula = "=SUM(B" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":B" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Formula = "=AVERAGE(C" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":C" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=SUM(D" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":D" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=AVERAGE(E" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":E" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        Set tempSumRow = tablesSheet.Range("A" + CStr(tRow) + ":E" + CStr(tRow))
        With tempSumRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With tempSumRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With

        '.Cells(
        'create space for new table (this leaves one row of space, increase to 3 or more if you wish)
        tRow = tRow + 2
    End With
Next ws
tablesSheet.Cells.Font.Name = "Arial" ' change this to your appropriate font
DeleteAll
tablesSheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Function InCollection(col As Collection, sKey As String) As Boolean

Dim bTest As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

bTest = IsObject(col(sKey))
If (Err = 0) Then
    InCollection = True
Else
    Err.Clear
End If

End Function
Private Sub DeleteAll()
Dim i As Integer
i = Worksheets.Count
For x = i To 3 Step -1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(x).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next x
End Sub
```

---

EDIT:

Ok. Redid code using arrays to store cell values prior to writing them to the tables sheet. It did slightly faster, 1 min 57 vs 2 min 22 for 15,000 rows. Here is the alternative code. Alter the button click to call this formula instead if you wish to use it. Note this code might be a bit more untidy, as I need to log off stackExchange now.

```
Private Sub SortNCopyTables2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim saleIDs() As Variant
Dim sellerClass() As Variant
Dim bucketClass() As Variant



Dim cashFlowSheet As Worksheet
Set cashFlowSheet = Worksheets("CashFlow")

Dim lastSaleIDRow As Long
lastSaleIDRow = cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

saleIDs = cashFlowSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastSaleIDRow).Value
sellerClass = cashFlowSheet.Range("B2:B" & lastSaleIDRow).Value
bucketClass = cashFlowSheet.Range("C2:C3" & lastSaleIDRow).Value

Dim classPairsArray() As Variant
Dim classPairs() As String
ReDim Preserve classPairs(0)
ReDim Preserve classPairsArray(0)
Dim size As Long
size = 0
Dim saleID As String

Dim tempArray() As String
For counter = 1 To UBound(saleIDs, 1)
    sellerBucketString = sellerClass(counter, 1) + " & " + bucketClass(counter, 1)

    If UBound(Filter(classPairs, sellerBucketString)) < 0 Then

        ReDim Preserve classPairs(size)

        classPairs(size) = sellerBucketString

        ReDim Preserve classPairsArray(size)

        ReDim Preserve tempArray(0)
        tempArray(0) = sellerBucketString

        classPairsArray(size) = tempArray

        size = size + 1
    End If

    Dim position As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(classPairsArray)
        tempArray = classPairsArray(i)

        If sellerBucketString = tempArray(0) Then
            tempArray = classPairsArray(i)
            ReDim Preserve tempArray(UBound(tempArray) + 1)
            tempArray(UBound(tempArray)) = saleIDs(counter, 1)

            classPairsArray(i) = tempArray
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i

Next counter

'loop through array and write to worksheet
Dim tablesSheet As Worksheet
Set tablesSheet = Worksheets("Tables")
'clear the tableSheet, just in case
tablesSheet.Rows(10 & ":" & tablesSheet.Rows.Count).Clear

Dim SaleIDRange, BalanceRange, MonthlyRange, RateRange As Range 'Change the letters and starting rows as necessary
Set SaleIDRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("A2:A" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
Set BalanceRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("D2:D" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)
Set MonthlyRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("E2:E" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row) ' not used now but assume is used for npv / price calcs
Set RateRange = cashFlowSheet.Range("F2:F" & cashFlowSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row)

Dim tRow As Long
tRow = 10 ' this is where I start to build my table
Dim row As Long
Dim tempSumRow As Range

For i = 0 To UBound(classPairsArray)
    Dim tableStartRow As Long
    tableStartRow = tRow + 1
    Dim tableSellerBucketGroup As String
    Dim tableArray() As String
    tableArray = classPairsArray(i)
    With tablesSheet
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = "Sale ID"
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Value = "NPV"
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Value = "Price"
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Value = "Balance"
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Value = "Rate"
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingleAccounting
        tRow = tRow + 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(tableArray)
            .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = tableArray(j)
            '.Cells(tRow, 2).Value = ??? NPV formula?
            '.Cells(tRow, 3).Value = ??? price formula?
            .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + BalanceRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0))"
            .Cells(tRow, 4).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=INDEX(" + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + RateRange.Address + ",MATCH(A" + CStr(tRow) + "," + cashFlowSheet.Name + "!" + SaleIDRange.Address + ",0))"
            .Cells(tRow, 5).NumberFormat = "0.0 %"
            tRow = tRow + 1
        Next j
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Value = tableArray(0)
        .Cells(tRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(tRow, 2).Formula = "=SUM(B" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":B" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        .Cells(tRow, 3).Formula = "=AVERAGE(C" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":C" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        .Cells(tRow, 4).Formula = "=SUM(D" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":D" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        .Cells(tRow, 5).Formula = "=AVERAGE(E" + CStr(tableStartRow) + ":E" + CStr(tRow - 1) + ")"
        Set tempSumRow = tablesSheet.Range("A" + CStr(tRow) + ":E" + CStr(tRow))
        With tempSumRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With tempSumRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        tRow = tRow + 2
    End With
Next i
tablesSheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah - I even tried to compile the code with the Collections data objects - but to no avail. I was getting a compile error due to the `SellerBucketString`, the error: Object required. So I removed the `Set` and still no luck, because then I got a type mismatch error. Also declared i and j as integer types to try and get it to compile, but I am stuck on the `SellerBucketString` variable.

Comment: To address the assumptions: 1. Yes, I can change the column references. 2. See above updated image of my tables tab to see what I am trying to insert into - remember, I just want to paste special values the sorted sales ID and not re-create the entire table (my fault, that I did not explain this well enough). 3. See above updated image to see my formulas -  i was impressed to see how you replicated INDEX MATCH formulas in vba.

Comment: 4. Hopefully you can see it by now (and I deeply appreciate how you have tackled this problem) - that all I want to do is copy and paste the sales ID into specially formatted tables in the Table tab. I just can't make the algorithm work to insert the rows needed to paste special values the sales ID

Comment: I think it is easier to havew this work for any number of Seller-Bucket pairs if you do not make and preformat the tables, and instead use the vba code to create and format the table for each seller-bucket combo it finds, like this code does. You just need to tweek the formatting to make it exactly like your management wants it to be. This has that a) it will work with all combos of seller-bucket, b) no empty tables c) no work pre-setuping the tables d) no need to have code always identifying the right table

Comment: True. Any thoughts about the SellerBucketstring error? I just want to run the code a few times to understand the collections data structure some more.

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Could cRow be pointing to wrong line?

Comment: And it could be a good idea to place a DeleteAll before the entire code if you are using the Collection method (the other one is better though), as having any of the temporary sheets in the code when the code runs (due to error on previous run) will cause errors.